# Django - filter a model with multiple parameters passing to function

Tags: python, django

I have a model as below

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Mobile(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and I need a query for filtering all Mobiles objects that have the same brand name equal to the input. Input have multiple entry. And it may has no entry, in this situation have to return all the objects.

```
def some_brand_mobiles(*brand_names):
   query = Mobile.objects.filter(brand__name=Q(brand_names))
   return query
```

Answer (score 0):

If brand_names is iterator (list, set ...), then can be achieve

```
def some_brand_mobiles(*brand_names):
   return Mobile.objects.filter(brand__name__in=brand_names)
```

Comment: it has an error in one cases:
Counter({<Mobile: Apple A80>: 1, <Mobile: Apple P[235 chars]: 1}) != Counter()

Comment: iterator must have string only